# Updating Inline Styling with removeAttribute() and setAttribute() not updating

Tags: javascript, css

Updated inline styling of a certain paragraph tag is not displaying new updates.

I am using the following example that I found on Stack overflow:

```
var para = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var len = para.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if(para[i].innerHTML.indexOf("SOME TEST") !== -1) {
        para[i].removeAttribute('style');
        para[i].setAttribute('style', 'FONT-SIZE: 100px !important; FONT-FAMILY: Arial !important; color:red;');
    }

}
```

When I look at the inspector tool, I am able to see the styling I implemented. However, the styling is not taking place.

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to make this work for IE8 and below

Comment: Have you tried using individual `element.style`? More about this here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: I'd recommend using a CSS class instead to toggle certain styles. Also, IE8 ***and below***?

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Yes. IE8 and below. The reason is the what is requested by the consumer.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro: I have tried this. However, I am unable to implement the "!important" part of it.

Comment: @INSGUEST Is there any reason of using JS styling instead of CSS classes?

Comment: @JimmyAdaro: The reason behind this is there is a file that is in play where the font size, font family, etc is set and using "!important" and being applied throughout all documents (the css is using the "*"). To override this, I would need to  implement !important to that section and I do not have access to modify such file

Comment: I understand this may not be something you can control, but it's far more likely that the customer just doesn't know what they are talking about and actually meant IE8 *and above*. Are you building software for machines running Windows 95? If so, you can toss out any idea of CSS3 or DOM Core level 2 (`getElementsByTagName`, etc.), or really even JavaScript since that first appeared in IE2. In fact, this question would really fall under *retrocomputing*.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro: I have also tried creating a class and doing the following: para[i].setAttribute("class", "democlass") where demo class contains the font-size and font-family. I am able to see the class inserted but it shows that class is empty

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I did spoke with the customer and were clear they wanted IE8 and below. I tried my best explaining the downfalls but were insistent that is what they want

Answer (score 0):

A better approach for styling an element using attributes, would be using **custom element attributes** and **specific CSS rules for those attributes**.

> **Note** : If you want to pass HTML validations, your attribute names **must be [prefixed](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) with 'data-'**. They should also not contain any uppercase letters.

In the following example, you will see how the styles declared with the `[data-myAttribute]` CSS selector are applied when the attribute is set to the element :

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');

// click event handler compatible with IE8
myElement.onclick = function clickHandler(e){
  // toggle the 'data-myAttribute' attribute
  if( myElement.hasAttribute('data-myAttribute') ){
    myElement.removeAttribute('data-myAttribute');
  }else{ 
    myElement.setAttribute('data-myAttribute', true);
  }
}
```

```css
[data-myAttribute]{
  text-decoration : underline;
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement">click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an alternative for old versions of IE, which neither support using setAttribute() to set styles nor event handlers. This also works in other browsers too:

```
var para = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var len = para.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if(para[i].innerHTML.indexOf("SOME TEST") !== -1) {
        para[i].style.cssText = 'FONT-SIZE: 100px !important; FONT-FAMILY: Arial !important; color:red;';
    }

}
```

On the other hand, I agree with the suggestion others have made that class switching is better when you're not using JS to calculate a value dynamically.

Comment: setAttribute is supported in internet explorer since IE6+

Comment: @colxi Perhaps I should have been clearer, but I didn't say it wasn't supported at all. I said it didn't work for two specific uses. And actually it's been (at least partially) supported since IE5.